# PyDrake ComputePointPairPenetration() kills kernel

Tags: drake

In calling `ComputePointPairPenetration()` from a QueryObject in Drake in Python in a Jupyter Notebook environment, `ComputePointPairPenetration()` reliably kills the kernel. I'm not sure what's causing it and couldn't figure out how to get any error message.

In case it's relevant I'm running pydrake locally on a Mac.

Here is relevant code:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.00001)
file_name = FindResource("models/robot.urdf")
model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
file_name = FindResource("models/object.urdf")
object_model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
plant.Finalize()

diagram = builder.Build()

# Run simulation...

# Get geometry info from scene graph
context = scene_graph.AllocateContext()
q_obj = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(context)
q_obj.ComputePointPairPenetration()
```

---

Edit: 
@Sherm's comment fixed my problem :) Thank you so much!

For reference:

```
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
scene_graph_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context) 
q_obj = scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval(scene_graph_context)
q_obj.ComputePointPairPenetration()
```

Comment: Multiple questions: 1.is "run simulation" required or does it crash without that? 2.If "run simulation" is required, can you include that code as well?  3. Can you elaborate on the geometries in `robot.urdf` and `object.urdf`?

Comment: Thank you for the question. Running simulation is not required for the crash. The above plus `diagram = builder.Build()` where `# Run simulation..` (as edited in the original post) is would reproduce the problem. For a minimum setting, removing the robot urdf only leaving the object urdf observes the same crash. The object urdf is a simple sphere that can move in the x and y directions through dummy prismatic joints.

Comment: It looks like you created a local Context for scene_graph. Instead I think you want the full diagram context so that the ports are connected up properly (e.g. scene_graph has an input port that receives poses from MultibodyPlant). So I think the above would work if you ask the Diagram to create a context, then ask for the SceneGraph subcontext for the calls you have above, rather than creating a standalone SceneGraph context.

Comment: subcontext = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context) lets you extract the fully-connected subcontext.

Comment: @Sherm actually paid attention to the code. Yes, your problem is that of passing an unconnected context. He should type that up in an answer so that it's more clearly broadcast (hint, hint, hint).

Comment: Your wish is my command. Copied my comment to an answer, trolling for upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a local `Context` for `scene_graph`. Instead you want the full diagram context so that the ports are connected up properly (e.g. `scene_graph` has an input port that receives poses from `MultibodyPlant`). So the above should work if you ask the `Diagram` to create a `Context`, then ask for the `SceneGraph` subcontext for the calls you have above, rather than creating a standalone `SceneGraph` context.

This lets you extract the fully-connected subcontext:

```
scene_graph_context = scene_graph.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
```

Answer (score 1):

FTR Here's a similar formulation in a Drake Python unittest:

[`TestPlant.test_scene_graph_queries`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/af1fc28a981ef501492f092ef492506659c9325a/bindings/pydrake/multibody/test/plant_test.py#L1340-L1344)

Note that this takes an alternate route (using `diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext` instead of `scene_graph.GetMyContextFromroot`), namely because it's doing scalar-type conversion as well.

If you're curious about scalar-type conversion (esp. if you're going to be doing optimization, e.g. needing `AutoDiffXd`), please see:

- Drake C++ API: [System Scalar Conversion Overview](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__system__scalar__conversion.html)
- Drake Python API: [`pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion.html)

Additionally, here are examples of scalar-converting both `MultibodyPlant` and `SceneGraph` for testing `InverseKinematics` constraint classes:

- [`inverse_kinematics.py: TestConstraints`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/af1fc28a981ef501492f092ef492506659c9325a/bindings/pydrake/multibody/test/inverse_kinematics_test.py#L353-L488)