# How to get geometric properties of bodies in Drake?

Tags: drake

I have a .urdf file specifying a group of obstacles, that I add to my simulation like this:

```
drake::systems::DiagramBuilder<double> builder;
auto [plant, scene_graph] =
    drake::multibody::AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, 0.0);

drake::multibody::Parser parser(&plant, &scene_graph);
auto obstacles = parser.AddModelFromFile("obstacles.urdf");
plant.WeldFrames(
        plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("ground", obstacles));
```

Where all the obstacles are fixed to a the "ground" object in the .urdf file by fixed joints, and to stop everything from falling down I welded the ground to the world frame.

**All the obstacles are boxes, and I need to extract the coordinates of the vertices of the boxes**. My plan was to get the `width`, `depth` and `height` properties of each of the `Box` shapes, in addition to their origins, and from this calculate the vertices (assuming none of the boxes are rotated). So far I have tried using `plant.GetBodiesWeldedTo()` and then `plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody()`, but I have not been able to extract the properties that I need.

How would one go about getting the vertices (or the position of the origin and width, depth and height) of the objects, after importing them into Drake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introspecting geometry is not straightforward. It requires "shape reification". Essentially, you have access to `Shape` but to find out what specific type of `Shape` it is, you run it through a `ShapeReifier`. An example of that can be found in [`ShapeName`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/geometry/shape_specification.h#L397-L437) which takes a generic shape and returns its name. What you want is something to extract box dimensions.

To extract pose, you'll also need access to a `QueryObject` from `SceneGraph`. To do that, you'll need to evaluate `SceneGraph`'s output port with an appropriate `Context`. I'm not going to focus on *acquiring* the `QueryObject` (we can open up a new stackoverflow question on that if necessary).

It's a multi-stage thing. We'll assume you started with `MultibodyPlant::GetCollisionGeometriesForBody`...

```cpp
class BoxExtractor : public ShapeReifier {
 public:
  explicit BoxExtractor(const Shape& shape) { shape.Reify(this); }

  std::optional<Box> box() const { return box_; }

 private:
  void ImplementGeometry(const Box& box, void*) override { box_ = box; }
  void ImplementGeometry(const Capsule&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const Cylinder&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const Convex&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const Ellipsoid&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const HalfSpace&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const Mesh&, void*) override {}
  void ImplementGeometry(const Sphere&, void*) override {}

  std::optional<Box> box_{};
};

const QueryObject<double>& query_object = ....;  // got it somehow.
const auto& inspector = scene_graph.model_inspector();
const auto& collision_geometries = plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody(some_body);
for (const GeometryId id : collision_geometries) {
  std::optional<Box> box = BoxExtractor(inspector.GetShape(id)).box();
  if (box) {
    const RigidTransformd& X_WB = query_object.X_WG(id);
    const Vector3d v_WBx = X_WB.rotation().col(0);
    const Vector3d v_WBy = X_WB.rotation().col(1);
    const Vector3d v_WBz = X_WB.rotation().col(2);
    const Vector3d& p_WBo = X_WB.translation();
    vector<Vector3d> corners;
    const Vector3d half_size{box->width(), box->depth(), box->height()};
    for (const double x_sign : {-1., 1.}) {
      for (const double y_sign : {-1., 1.}) {
        for (const double z_sign : {-1., 1.}) {
          corners.emplace_back(x_sign * half_size(0) * v_WBx +
                               y_sign * half_size(1) * v_WBy +
                               z_sign * half_size(2) * v_WBz);
        }
      }
    }
    // Do stuff with the eight corners.
  }
}
```

(I'm about 98% sure the code will work as is... I typed it on the fly and can't guarantee it'll just copy and paste.)

Edit --

I realized I only answered *half* of your question. How to get box dimensions. You still want to know *where* the box is so you can compute box vertices. I've modified the example code to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out! I managed to get the `query_object` by doing the following:
`const auto context = scene_graph.CreateDefaultContext();`
`const auto& query_object =`
`scene_graph.get_query_output_port().Eval<drake::geometry::QueryObject<double>>(*context);`

However, I get a segmentation fault when I run this line: `const auto X_WB = query_object.X_WG(id);`

Not sure exactly what the problem is, but I am guessing that it has something to do with the context I used to get `query_object`. Do you have any idea what is causing this fault?

Comment: Or do I maybe need to register the obstacles with the scene_graph? I figured that parser would do this automatically when instantiating the parser as `drake::multibody::Parser parser(&plant, &scene_graph);`, but maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: I was able to figure it out! For reference, I found the solution to the seg fault here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668510/pydrake-computepointpairpenetration-kills-kernel

Answer (score 0):

I know Python isn't the language for this question, but I would still like to complement Sean's answer with the Python API ;)

Here's an example of doing `SceneGraph`-only shape introspection:

- Unofficial example (for a basic Rviz usage): [`drake_ros1_hacks/_ros_geometry.py`](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/69b3a7142cb36777a05084ce2f15c25da99a5b46/ros/drake_ros1_hacks/_ros_geometry.py#L93-L123) - includes Python's version of the reifier (`if type(shape) == ...`)

Along the lines of exercising the mapping between `SceneGraph` and `MultibodyPlant` in Python:

- Drake unittest: [`plant_test.py`, MBP <-> SG queries](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/af1fc28a981ef501492f092ef492506659c9325a/bindings/pydrake/multibody/test/plant_test.py#L1317-L1389)
- Drake tutorials: [MultibodyPlant rendering, making rendering labels](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/af1fc28a9/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb#Change-labels-to-model-instance-by-direct-remapping.)